# CSS navigation bar overwriting bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

everyone my navigation bar is overwriting to my bootstrap modal. so my bootstrap  modal header is not displaying properly. I want to display it properly. how can I resolve this issue? I am weak in English please apologize me if I made any Grammatical or Spelling mistakes.

Website Adress:

http://sale.coupsoft.com/view/index/468405

click on Phone Number than bootstrap modal will appear.

[image: navigation bar overwriting bootstrap modal]

Comment: This will be a `z-index` problem. but you will need to share some code, so we can see how to help you

Comment: @Andrew it's true that z-index problem but I want to display my bootstrap modal header clear. How can I share very big CSS code to you? but you can visit my website http://sale.coupsoft.com/view/index/468405 and then click on Phone Number so you will see this issue.

Comment: on your class `.navbar` your `z-index` is too high. you need to reduce the number. i changed it to 1 and it worked.

Comment: checkout my updated answer it solved ur problem

Comment: @Rahul thanks it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its zindex issue, you should inspect element ur code and set zindex of nav below modal like

```
.navbar{
  z-index: 100;
}
```